# jquery sends form data on post request but when i modify servlet to return json & modify jquery to accept json servlet is not receiving null

Tags: java, jquery, json, jsp, servlets

My im sending jquery to a servlet and try to connect with db. it is working good.
But when I try to return json from servlet and modify jsp to accept json type. the parameters received by servlet are null why??
Waiting for the solution...

Here is my code:

```
function submitData()
{
    alert('Called');
    $('document').ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'/DashBoard/FetchAlerts',  
            type:'post',
            dataType:'json',
            data: $('#dataForm').serialize(),
            cache: false,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(data) {
                alert('Yes!');
                $.each(data.obj,function(index,obj)
                        {
                    alert('Date:'+obj.date+'Hour:'+obj.hours);
                    })
            } 
            });
    });
}
```

if i remove lines datatype and contentType or set contentType to application/www-x-urlencoded servlet is receiving parameters.

Here is my servlet code:

```html
response.setContentType("application/json");
  int startHour,startMinute,endHour,endMinute;
  String temp[];
  Calendar cal;
  out=response.getWriter();
  System.out.println("Url Called");
  String startDate=request.getParameter("startDate");
  System.out.println(request.getParameter("startDate"));
  System.out.println(request.getAttribute("startDate"));
  Timestamp startTDate,endTDate;
  if(startDate==null||startDate.trim().isEmpty())
  {
   startDate=new Date()+"";
  }
  String endDate=request.getParameter("endDate");
  if(endDate==null||endDate.trim().isEmpty())
  {
   endDate=new Date()+"";
  }
  String color=request.getParameter("color");
  if(color==null||color.trim().isEmpty())
  {
   color="Red";
  }
  String startTime=request.getParameter("startTime");
  if(startTime==null||startTime.trim().isEmpty())
  {
   startTime=new Date().getTime()+"";
  }
  temp=startTime.split(" ");
  temp=temp[0].split(":");
  try{
   startHour=Integer.parseInt(temp[0]);
  }catch(NumberFormatException ne){
   startHour=0;
  }
  if(startHour+""=="12")
  startMinute=Integer.parseInt(temp[1]);
  else
   startMinute=Integer.parseInt(temp[1])+12;
  
  
  String endTime=request.getParameter("endTime");
  if(endTime==null||endTime.trim().isEmpty())
  {
   endTime=new Date().getTime()+"";
  }
  temp=endTime.split(" ");
  temp=temp[0].split(":");
  try{
   endHour=Integer.parseInt(temp[0]); 
  }catch(NumberFormatException ne){
   endHour=0;
  }
  if(endHour+""=="12")
   endMinute=0;
   else
    endMinute=Integer.parseInt(temp[1]);
  String searchText=request.getParameter("searchTextBox");
  if(searchText.trim().isEmpty())
  {
   searchText="";
  }
  String radio1=request.getParameter("radio1");
  if(radio1.trim().isEmpty())
  {
   radio1="All";
  }
  System.out.println("Status:"+radio1);
  try{
   SimpleDateFormat from=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
   SimpleDateFormat to=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
   Date date=from.parse(startDate);
   System.out.println("Date:"+date);
   startDate=to.format(date);
   cal=GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
   cal.set(Calendar.DATE, date.getDate());
   cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, date.getMonth());
   cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, date.getYear()+1900);
   cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, date.getHours());
   cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, date.getMinutes());
   startTDate=new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());
   date=from.parse(endDate);
   System.out.println("Date1:"+date);
   cal=GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
   cal.set(Calendar.DATE, date.getDate());
   cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, date.getMonth());
   cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, date.getYear()+1900);
   cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, date.getHours());
   cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, date.getMinutes());
   endTDate=new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());
   endDate=to.format(date);
   sql="select * from alerts where Date BETWEEN '"+startTDate+"' AND '"+endTDate+"' AND color='"+color+"'AND Status='"+radio1+"'";
  }
  catch(ParseException p){
   
  }
  catch(NullPointerException ne){
   
  }
  try{
   
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
      stmt=conn.createStatement();
   rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
   JSONObject json=new JSONObject();
   JSONArray obj;
   obj=new JSONArray();
   while(rs.next()){
    JSONObject ob1=new JSONObject();
    Timestamp tem=rs.getTimestamp("Date");
    SimpleDateFormat s1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    try{
     Date d1=s1.parse(tem+"");
     int hour=d1.getHours();
     int min=d1.getMinutes();
     s1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
     ob1.put("Date", d1);
     ob1.put("Hours",hour);
     ob1.put("Minutes",min);
     ob1.put("Status", rs.getString("Status"));
     ob1.put("Color",rs.getString("Color"));
     ob1.put("Description", rs.getString("Description"));
     
    }catch(ParseException p){
     
    }
    catch(JSONException je){
     
    }
    
   }
   json.put("obj", obj);
   out.print(json);
   rs.close();
   stmt.close();
   conn.close();
  }
  catch(SQLException sq){
   
   
  }
  catch(ClassNotFoundException ce){
   
  }
  catch(JSONException je){
   
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution guys...
i replaced content type with this application/x-www-form-urlencoded  and it is working now...
Thank you